# Can I drag an item from one accordion to another?

Tags: jquery, web, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Is it possible to add an item to an accordion-control by dragging it from another accordion?

1. I created an accordion named `MainAccordion`
2. I created another accordion named `MenuAccordion`
3. I want to drag item from `MenuAccordion` to `MainAccordion`

Comment: Well maybe try using the dragabler ability of jquery ui, and check drag stop position and if it's on the 2nd according by px or something do the right logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, though you may need to code a little. I have whipped up a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LfaRk/1/

Let's go through it. The HTML is simple, same with the CSS.

The JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#catalog").accordion();
    $("#catalog2").accordion();
    $("#catalog h2").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#catalog2").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var content = ui.draggable.next();
            ui.draggable.draggable('disable').appendTo(this);
            content.appendTo(this);
            $("#catalog").accordion('destroy').accordion();
            $("#catalog2").accordion('destroy').accordion();
        }
    });
});
```

So what am I doing?

- I'm initializing the 2 accordions, with [`.accordion()`](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).
- I'm making the headers of the first accordion [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).
- I'm making the second accordion [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

(The code I have started off on is: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart, you should check it out too)

Let's see the drop callback on the second accordion:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    var content = ui.draggable.next();
    ui.draggable.draggable('disable').appendTo(this);
    content.appendTo(this);
    $("#catalog").accordion('destroy').accordion();
    $("#catalog2").accordion('destroy').accordion();
}
```

What is happening here?

The `ui.draggable` is the jQuery wrapped element that is dragged at the moment. I will need to insert it into the second accordion. Therefore I could call `ui.draggable.appendto(this)`, but it will remain draggable, so I need to make it non draggable too.

I need to move the content with the header, so I select the content with: `var content = ui.draggable.next()` and then move it with: `content.appendTo(this);`. `this` is still the element which is droppable (the second accordion).

Finally I need to reinitialize the accordions, so that the elements recognise where they are:

```
$("#catalog").accordion('destroy').accordion();
$("#catalog2").accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

And it's ready.

If you want to make the items draggable back and forth you might need to code a little more. Also if you want the accordions to be sortable, droppable and sortable seems to interact in funny ways, so a little experimenting might be needed.